# loop a list of ids as parameters in api, storing each call of json results in a dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, api, loops

I'm trying to loop a list of match ids (LMID5) as parameters for api calls. I think I have the looping the API calls correct as it prints the urls but I'm struggling to store the results every time in the same dataframe.

The results of the API come through in JSON. Which I then normalise into a DF.

When just using one parameter to call api this is how I code it and create a df.

```
matchDetails = ('https://api.football-data-api.com/match?key=&match_id=1308560')
responsematchDetails = requests.get(url = matchDetails)
dfLM = pd.json_normalize(responseleagueMatches.json()['data'])
```

The below code is what I have wrote to try loop many calls to API using parameters from a list, but I'm struggling to store the data each time.

```
dfMatchDetails = pd.DataFrame()
for i in list(LMID5):
    url = 'https://api.football-data-api.com/match?key=&match_id=' + str(i)
    rm = requests.get(url)
    print(url)
    for match in pd.json_normalize(rm.json()["data"]):
            dfMatchDetails = dfMatchDetails.append({[match]
            }, ignore_index=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Concat the table with new data?

Comment: Apologies, not sure I was clear. Every time I loop through using list to call api, I want to store the data from each call.